# Is it possible to max out all vocation for 1 character?

Tags: dragons-dogma

Is it posible or isn't there is enough experience and vocation point to max out every vocation for your main character?.

Or mayby you reach max level before one could finish more than 2 completely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum level up to which you get stat gains is 200. The amount of discipline earned is linked to the amount of experience you gain from slaying monsters and finishing quests, with larger rewards providing a less efficient ratio of Experience to Discipline.

[image]

The X axis shows the amount of experience gained.
The Y axis shows amount of discipline gained proportional to the experience.

As you can see, the bigger the EXP reward, the less efficient is the DP reward in relationship to the EXP.

**EDIT:** Going past level 200 will show your level with an infinity sign instead of digits. Leveling past 200 will not provide stat gains (as mentioned above), but will continue to provide Discipline Points.

**EDIT:** The less pawns you have, the higher is the exp gain for killing enemies, as provided [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/626515-dragons-dogma/62668891).

Comment: I see, so as per the table the best dp gains are in the 500 -1000 exp gains, will accept answer once 24 hourse have passed if there is no better response

Comment: @xerido M8, there's new info.

Comment: well that is really useful mate, thanks for improving the answer